# Efficient way to erase and re create a (part of, if possible) subplot inside loop using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, data-visualization, analytics

The code below creates a Scatter plot from `X` and based on values of `w,b`, creates lines over X.

I have tried a couple of combinations such as:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()

plt.clf
plt.cla
```

But they either seem to plot multiple lines over the plot or Delete the figure  / axes.

**Is it possible to plot the Scatter plot only once but the Lines keep changing based on  `w,b`?**.

Below is the code that I have used:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

def get_hyperplane_value(x, w, b, offset):
    '''
    Generate Hyperplane for the plot
    '''
    return (-w[0] * x + b + offset) / w[1]


def plot_now(ax, W,b):
    '''
    Visualise the results
    '''
    x0_1 = np.amin(X[:, 0])
    x0_2 = np.amax(X[:, 0])

    x1_1 = get_hyperplane_value(x0_1, W, b, 0)
    x1_2 = get_hyperplane_value(x0_2, W, b, 0)

    x1_1_m = get_hyperplane_value(x0_1, W, b, -1)
    x1_2_m = get_hyperplane_value(x0_2, W, b, -1)

    x1_1_p = get_hyperplane_value(x0_1, W, b, 1)
    x1_2_p = get_hyperplane_value(x0_2, W, b, 1)

    ax.plot([x0_1, x0_2], [x1_1, x1_2], "y--")
    ax.plot([x0_1, x0_2], [x1_1_m, x1_2_m], "k")
    ax.plot([x0_1, x0_2], [x1_1_p, x1_2_p], "k")

    x1_min = np.amin(X[:, 1])
    x1_max = np.amax(X[:, 1])
    ax.set_ylim([x1_min - 3, x1_max + 3])
    
    ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker="o", c = y)
    return ax



X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=50, n_features=2, centers=2, cluster_std=1.05, random_state=40)
y = np.where(y == 0, -1, 1)


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    
for i in range(50):
    
    W = np.random.randn(2)
    b = np.random.randn()
    
    ax.cla()
    ax = plot_now(ax, W, b)
    
    display(fig)    
    clear_output(wait = True)
    plt.pause(0.25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you are trying to animate a figure, so you should use `FuncAnimation`. The basic principle with animations is that you initialize your lines, and later update the values.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def get_hyperplane_value(x, w, b, offset):
    '''
    Generate Hyperplane for the plot
    '''
    return (-w[0] * x + b + offset) / w[1]

def get_weights_bias(i):
    W = np.random.randn(2)
    b = np.random.randn()
    return W, b

def plot_now(i):
    # retrieve weights and bias at iteration i
    W, b = get_weights_bias(i)
    
    x0_1 = np.amin(X[:, 0])
    x0_2 = np.amax(X[:, 0])

    x1_1 = get_hyperplane_value(x0_1, W, b, 0)
    x1_2 = get_hyperplane_value(x0_2, W, b, 0)

    x1_1_m = get_hyperplane_value(x0_1, W, b, -1)
    x1_2_m = get_hyperplane_value(x0_2, W, b, -1)

    x1_1_p = get_hyperplane_value(x0_1, W, b, 1)
    x1_2_p = get_hyperplane_value(x0_2, W, b, 1)

    line1.set_data([x0_1, x0_2], [x1_1, x1_2])
    line2.set_data([x0_1, x0_2], [x1_1_m, x1_2_m])
    line3.set_data([x0_1, x0_2], [x1_1_p, x1_2_p])

    x1_min = np.amin(X[:, 1])
    x1_max = np.amax(X[:, 1])
    ax.set_ylim([x1_min - 3, x1_max + 3])

X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=50, n_features=2, centers=2, cluster_std=1.05, random_state=40)
y = np.where(y == 0, -1, 1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker="o", c = y) # ax.scatter

# initialize empty lines
line1, = ax.plot([], [], "y--")
line2, = ax.plot([], [], "k")
line3, = ax.plot([], [], "k")

# create an animation with 10 frames
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, plot_now, frames=range(10), repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Running this code just shows the scatter plots, once, without the lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running this on Jupyter?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jupyter.

Comment: To run animation into Jupyter I usually execute this command at the start of the notebook: `%matplotlib tk` . You need to have `tkinter` installed. Otherwise, run the code from a standard Python console.